# findAndModify with skip

Tags: mongodb, findandmodify

How to skip some documents when using `findAndModify` (or `findOneAndUpdate`) in `MongoDB`?
[Documentation suggests that it is possible](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/#using--skip-with-sorted-results), but [findAndModify](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.findAndModify) and [findOneAndUpdate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) don't specify `skip` argument.